Extracting frame out of video based on time in seconds
I'm developing a web-based video editing tool where users can pause a video and draw circles or lines on it using canvas. When a user pauses the video, I retrieve the current playback time in seconds using the HTML5 video.currentTime property. I then send this time value along with the shape details to the server. On the server-side, we use FFmpeg to extract the specific paused frame from the video. The issue I'm encountering is a frame mismatch between the one displayed in the browser and the one generated in the backend using FFmpeg.
I've experimented with various approaches for this process.
Extracting frame based on time. Example: in this case time is 3.360 second.

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:03.360 -frames:v 1 frame.jpg

Converting time to frame number using the following logic: Math.round(video.currentTime * fps)

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select=eq(n,101)" -vsync vfr frame.jpg


ffmpeg -i input .mp4 -vf "select='lt(t,3.360)lt(3.360-t,1/31.019)',setpts=N/(31.019TB)" -vsync 0 frame.jpg

The challenge I'm facing is that sometimes the frame I see in the browser at the pause time doesn't match the one generated in the backend using FFmpeg. How can I solve this problem? If it's an issue with currentTime, are there any other approaches I can try?

I would recommend generating a video file that shows the expected timestamp on each frame. then you can know which side is wrong (assuming the generated video is correct). -- do not, never ever deal with "frame numbers". it's all timestamps, down to how the file is read and written. there are no "frame numbers". you can count frames, but for indexing/seeking, it must be a timestamp.
